# Store value of a SimpleXML node even if it updates

Tags: php, simplexml

I am trying to store the value of an xml node and keep it the same even if it updates.

If I do:

```
$sxml->node = 1;
$blah = $sxml->node;
echo($blah . "<br />");
$sxml->node = 2;
echo($blah . "<br />");
```

The output will be

```
1
2
```

I want $blah to stay the same regardless of what happens to $sxml->node. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Type cast](http://php.net/manual/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting) the SimpleXML object given by `$sxml->node` to a string:

```
$blah = (string) $sxml->node;
```

This prevents the [object's](http://php.net/oop) properties from being updated.